# Travis CI and JUnit with Gradle cannot find classpath resources

Tags: java, gradle, junit, classpath, travis-ci

I have a project whose complete source you can find at its GitHub page [here](https://github.com/team-jtrial/jtrial-ci/tree/feat/config) on the `feat/config` branch.  The problem I am having is that `ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` always returns `null`, and creating a `File` with the complete path (including the source directory) also returns a `FileNotFoundException`.

This code should load the default configuration values out of a classpath resource and write it to a `File`.  It works locally but fails on Travis CI.

```
public static void writeDefault(String res, File out) throws IOException {
    if (!out.exists()) {
        out.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        out.createNewFile();
    }
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(out);
    InputStream in = FileConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(res);
    if (in == null) {
        stream.close();
        throw new FileNotFoundException(res);
    }
    IOUtils.copy(in, stream);
    stream.close();
}

@Test
public void testFileConfig() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Creating default config file");
    File testConfigFile = new File("configs/test.txt");
    if (!testConfigFile.exists())
        FileConfig.writeDefault("configs/test.txt", testConfigFile);
    System.out.println("Loading config file");
    Config testConfig = FileConfig.loadConfig(testConfigFile);
    System.out.println("Loaded value: " + testConfig.getValue("value-1"));
    System.out.println("Deleting config file");
    testConfigFile.deleteOnExit();
}
```

The above test fails with the following stack trace:

```
jtrial.config.TestConfig > testFileConfig STANDARD_OUT
    Creating default config file
jtrial.config.TestConfig > testFileConfig FAILED
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: configs/test.txt
        at jtrial.config.FileConfig.writeDefault(FileConfig.java:111)
        at jtrial.config.TestConfig.testFileConfig(TestConfig.java:24)
```

`.travis.yml` config file:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
notifications:
  email: false
install:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - ./gradlew --info assemble
script: ./gradlew --info check
```

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahem... PREPARE TO CRINGE AND FACEPALM!

I just realized... that... I had `configs/` on the `.gitignore` file.  This wasn't only ignoring the `configs/` directory in the root project directory, but every instance of `configs/`.  I just replaced it with `./configs/` and then ACTUALLY added the text files to a new commit. *facepalms to a new dimension*

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is caused by this Gradle issue: [src/test/resources not added to classpath intermittently](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-939).