# Travis CI + Maven + Junit getClass().getResourceAsStream() not working

Tags: java, maven, junit, travis-ci

I am working on a Java Maven project and am using Travis CI. I am trying to read am image file as InputStream from a Junit Test class using the following code

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("treadmill.jpg");
```

The image file is stored in the same package as the Junit Test file. This code works on my local Windows 10 system but it returns null in Travis CI.

`.travis.yml` config file

```
language: java
services:
- mysql
before_install:
- mysql -u root < db_schema/dbschema.sql
- mysql -u root -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somepassword');"
```

I have also looked at [Travis CI and JUnit with Gradle cannot find classpath resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636089/travis-ci-and-junit-with-gradle-cannot-find-classpath-resources).

Any help will be appreciated.